# The Zencoder API library is not installed ... zencoder in a library path such as sites/all/libraries

Tags: files

I have installed Zencoder 2.1.1 for my Drupal 7.22 but it's not working as I see the following error:

```
The Zencoder API library is not installed. Download the library and install it to a directory called zencoder in a library path such as sites/all/libraries.
```

I have already done what it required:

```
[root@ip-10-128-146-179 libraries]# pwd
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/libraries
[root@ip-10-128-146-179 libraries]# ls -lrt zencoder/Services/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7867 Jul 21 16:32 Zencoder.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 16:32 Zencoder
[root@ip-10-128-146-179 libraries]# ls -lrt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 21 16:32 zencoder
```

What do I need to now?

[Screehshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs1He.png)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring webserver and it's libraries, not about using them with Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared all caches and ran cron and that solved the problem.

Thanks to [this](https://drupal.org/node/1468008).